# Inequation with absolute values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

How would one proceed in solving this difficult inequation with multiple absolute values?
is there a way one should proceed ?

$$\frac{x}{||x|-2|} \le \frac{x-1}{|x-3|}$$

thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Discuss several cases: 
$$x\in(-\infty,-2)\cup(-2 ,0]\; ; \; x\in(0 ,2)\; ;\; x\in(2 ,3)\; ;\; x\in(3 ,+\infty)$$

Comment: @franck It might also help to cross multiply the fractions as well.

Comment: @Ataraxia how come  don't we consider the case from x ∈ (1,2) ?

Comment: @franck The $x-1$ doesn't form its own separate case because it's not absolute valued in the equation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AndréNicolas